# Submit a form inside iframe and result to outside

Tags: jquery, iframe

How can we submit a form from an iframe and the result to the outside?

```
$('iframe#paymentFrame form').attr('target', '_top');
```

I tried with this code and it doesn't work. Can I do that with jQuery or any other way to do this? I can't use `target="_top"` directly as I am loading form of payment gateway inside iframe.

Comment: when are you calling this `$('iframe#paymentFrame form').attr('target', '_top');`? I mean on which event?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar on $(document).ready(function())

Comment: are you getting any console errors? after setting target="_top", it should come out of frame and display in full page.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar that attr is not setting for the form, i have checked by inspecting the elemnt.So you are telling it is possible to set attr like this?  <iframe  width="700" height="900" scrolling="No" frameborder="0" name="paymentFrame" id="paymentFrame"  src="${url}">
</iframe>  this is my iframe code and url is setting from java.

Comment: check if you are able to get the form instance correctly. check `$('iframe#paymentFrame form').attr('action')` by putting alert and see if this gives you correct value.